# ostream::write not writing entire struct?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to export various values, such as ints and simple structs, to a binary file. Here's some code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdint>
using namespace std;

template<class T> void writeToStream(ostream& o, T& val)
{
    o.write((char*)&val, sizeof(T));
    cout << o.tellp() << endl;  //always outputs 4
}

struct foo {
    uint16_t a, b;
};

int main()
{
    foo myFoo = {42, 42};
    ofstream test("test.txt", ios::binary);
    writeToStream(test, myFoo);
    test.close();
}
```

The program should generate an output file 4 bytes long. But when I open it, it's only 2 bytes long. If I change `myFoo.a` and `myFoo.b` to contain values of 256 or more (requires more than 1 byte to store), then the file becomes 4 bytes long. I'm using the Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview on Win7; I haven't checked to see if the same happens on other systems or compilers. How can I make it output correctly for values of a or b under 256?

Comment: How are you determining the length of the file?

Comment: Well, I was opening it in notepad++, and it displayed it as 2 characters for values under 256, 4 otherwise. However, I if I right click on the file and click "properties" it shows me 4 bytes...

Comment: I think therein lies your issue; you're trying to determine binary file-size by viewing it in a text editor.

Comment: File size is actually stupidly complicated if you use tools. Just fopen() it, fseek() to the end, and ftell() to see how big it is. The problem you are working on is known as "serialization." Using plain-old C functions to write would help you here, you don't have a lot of control over exactly what ostream outputs in this case, and reading it back in is much more problematic. Whereas with fwrite() you can tell it exactly what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A file can only be read back by a program that understands the format in which it was stored. Notepad++ has no understanding of the format in which your file was stored, so it has no ability to read it back and render it sensibly. Either write the file in a format Notepad++ understands, such as ASCII text, or only read the file with a program that understand the format you wrote it in.

Comment: Or determine the file size by using a file browser or terminal command…

Comment: I guess I was thrown off because Notepad++ usually shows me null characters and that kind of stuff. However, I confirmed with a hex editor that Notepad++ was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I have cleaned up your code as follows.  Though I do not know why the old code output two bytes, the new code does output four.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdint>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::uint16_t;
using std::ostream;
using std::ofstream;
using std::ios;

template <class T> void writeToStream(ostream& o, T& val)
{
    o.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&val), sizeof(T));
    cout << o.tellp() << endl;  //always outputs 4
}

struct foo {
    uint16_t a, b;
};

int main()
{
    foo myFoo = {42, 42};
    ofstream test("test.txt", ios::binary);
    writeToStream(test, myFoo);
    // Just let the stream "test" pass out of scope.
    // It closes automatically.
    //test.close();
    return 0;
}
```

(My standard library lacks *cstdint,* so I used `short` rather than `uint16_t,` but I doubt that this matters.)

The `std::ofstream` type is derived from `std::ostream`.  The `writeToStream()` function is happier, or at least more regular and more general, if passed a plain `std::ostream`.  Also, for information: to issue `using namespace std;` is almost never recommended in C++.

Good luck.

Comment: It appears that your program is identical to his, and it works because his already worked too.